# C++ can't get bubble sort to work when extracting data from txt

Tags: c++, text-files, ifstream, bubble-sort

I'm fairly new to programming, and am struggling to get bubble sort to work when reading values from a txt file. Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("D:/University/Physics/3 - Third Year/C++/2/simpledata.txt");
char myArray[100];

if( myFile.is_open() ){
    while( !myFile.eof() ){
        myFile >> myArray;
        cout << myArray << endl;
    }

}

bool swap=false;

do{
swap=false;
for(int i=0; i<36; i++){
            if(myArray[i] > myArray[i+1])
            {
                float temp = myArray[i+1];
                myArray[i+1] = myArray[i];
                myArray[i] = temp;

                swap=true;

            }

        }
}while(swap==true);


for(int i=0; i<37; i++)
{
    std::cout << myArray[i] << ",";
}

std::cout << std::endl;

return 0;

myFile.close();
return 0;

}
```

And here is the data in my txt file:

> 1 4 5 6 8 7 6.3 5.2 18 17.1 -3.2 -4 -5 -4 1 2 7 9 20 21.1 22 22.3 14 15 12 12.1 11 1 6 7 4 -1 8 17.2 16 13.1 15

Now the bubble sort works perfectly when I make an array in the program, however when trying the same after reading the data from txt file to 'myArray', I get lot's of weird symbols like this: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠.

One thing I tried was to change 'char myArray[100]' to 'float myArray[100]' but that gave problems of its own.

Any help is appreciated, and if I have been too vague I apologise.

Comment: That file is just a bunch of space-separated numbers? And you're just slurping that line of numbers into a char array? myarray[0] might be `1`, but myarray[1]` is going to be a space char, etc... you need to split that array up into individual integers first. remember that `200` as a string is 3 bytes/chars (or more if you've got a unicode file), while 200 as an integer is 1 byte.

Comment: Are you kidding? You're reading the data as a string (into the array), what exactly are you expecting to happen when you try to sort those characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to float myArray[100], but then your file reading code should be like this.

```
if( myFile.is_open() ){
    float* tempArr = myArray;
    while( myFile >> *tempArr ){
        cout << *tempArr << endl;
        ++tempArr;
    }
}
```

full code example is here

http://codepad.org/LTQ402pE

Answer (score 0):

you have mistakes in your sorting and why you don't declare directly an array of doubles instead of chars?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open("D:/University/Physics/3 - Third Year/C++/2/simpledata.txt");
    double myArray[37];
    int i = 0;

    if( myFile.is_open() )
    {
        while( myFile >> myArray[i] )
        {
            cout << myArray[i] << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for( i = 0; i < 37; i++)
    {
        for(int j = (i + 1); j < 37; j++)
        {
            if(myArray[i] > myArray[j])
            {
                double temp = myArray[i];
                myArray[i] = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for( i = 0; i < 37; i++)
    {
        std::cout << myArray[i] << ",";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;

    myFile.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: however you can first read any file and count how many numbers there then create dynamically an array and read again filling this array then sort and print